# CSOM content type

Tags: development, csom

I have an issue with CSOM and content type, I used CSOM to read some value in a sharepoint list, it works well until I try to used content type
If I create a new content type with my fields, it's worked but if I add my field in an existing content type. It doesn't work and that's return me the following error:

```
Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

the error it's comming from the first line which try to read my field so in my code here the line:

```
if (item[l_strUniqueKeyName].ToString() == l_strUniqueKeyValue)
```

I've done a lot of researches but I found nothing related to this issue

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the ContentType field value is null, if it is null, then call.ToString() method, it will throw "Object reference not set to an instance of object" exception.